# Counting elements in an array greater than next element C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Why is it giving wrong count
In this question we have to find out how many elements are greater than the next element of an array
#include 
using namespace std;

```
    int main() {
    //number of testcases
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        while(t--){
//taking number of elements in an array
            int n,count;
            cin>>n;
//taking array
            int a[n];
            count=0;
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
                cin>>a[n];
            }
//checking array 
        for(int j=1;j<=n-1;j++){
     
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                count++;
            }
               
        }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    }
        return 0;
    }
```

Input
5
1 2 3 4 1
Expected Output
1
Output through above code
2

Comment: You're going out of bounds of the arrays `a` when your wrote: `cin>>a[n]` so undefined behavior. Also, index starts from `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several **problems** with your code:

##### Problem 1

You're going out of bounds of the array `a` which leads to **undefined behavior**, when you wrote

```
cin >> a[n];  //undefined behavior
```

Note that indexing of arrays starts from `0` instead of `1` in C++.

##### Problem 2

In standard C++, the size of an array must be a **compile-time constant**. This mean the following is incorrect in your code:

```
int n;
cin>>n;

int a[n];   //NOT STANDARD C++ BECAUSE n IS NOT A CONSTANT EXPRESSION
```

---

Better would be to use `std::vector` instead of built in array.

```
int n = 0;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> a(n);   //this creates a vector of size n

//take input from user
for(int& element: a)
{
    std::cin >> element;
} 
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i< n - 1; ++i)
{
    if(a[i] > a[i+1])
    {
        ++count;
    }
}
```